# Split DataTable without using AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, datatable, asenumerable, datasetextensions

I am writing a C# script that will be run inside another project that makes use of the C# compiler. This engine does not have `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` referenced nor will it be allowed to do so.

That being said I still need to take a DataTable of 100,000 rows and break it up into smaller DataSets of 10,000 rows max. Normally I would use `DataExtensions` with something like ..

```
var filteredDataTable = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(10000).CopyToDataTable();
```

What would be an efficient way to go about this without using `DataSetExtensions`? Should I be resigned to using a `foreach loop` and copying over 10,000 rows into new `DataTables`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be resigned to using a foreach loop and copying over 10,000
>   rows into new DataTables?

Yes, also you may consider writing your own extension method to slice the table and reuse it wherever required. Something like below -

```
public DataTable  SliceTable(this DataTable dt, int rowsCount, int skipRows=0)
{
     DataTable dtResult = dt.Clone();
     for (int i = skipRows; i < dt.Rows.Count && rowsCount > 0; i++)
     {
         dtResult.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
         rowsCount --;
     }

     return dtResult;
}
```

Uses-

```
DataTable myData; -- Original table
var slice1 = myData.SliceTable(1000); // get slice of first 1000 rows
var slice2 = myData.SliceTable(1000,1000); // get rows from 1001 to 2000
var slice3 = myData.SliceTable(1000,2000); // get rows from 2001 to 3000
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you!